# How to dynamically add input without ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have that question, I am looking for examples everywhere and all I see are those examples of adding inputs with `ng-repeat`, but I don't want that, all I want is to have a button which says `add another input` and once the user click on it, have a new input text below the existing one.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input ng-model="operation.detailText" type="text">
    <div ng-show="operation.detailText.length">
      <p ng-show="operation.detailText.length">{{operation.detailText}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats the problem with `ng-repeat`?

Comment: He doesn't want to add inputs in a loop, he wants to have a button that on click, it will add another input bellow the last added input. I believe he wants to do a dynamic form.

Comment: ng-repeat really is the way to go on this one.
How else will you determine where to store the data from the input?

Comment: @taxicala. It can still be achived by ng-repeat

Comment: @Zee so how I do it with ng-repeat ?

Comment: If you have a finite set of inputs that can be shown you can write the html for them yourself and ng-show them when appropriate. If you want an indeterminate number of inputs, it sounds like you'll have an array of inputs. I'm not sure how you would do it without ng-repeat. There might be a custom directive you could make, but I'm not familiar enough with making directives

Comment: I am quite familiar with making directives, and it could be done like that. The problem you'd run into is getting the results out of those inputs. Without some array or object to loop through and pull out that differentiated data, you're out of luck, but if you have such an array or object then you don't need that directive because ng-repeat is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need. You can do this with either ng-repeat or ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end (the latter results in fewer html elements, but for simplicity I'll just use ng-repeat here):

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="operation in operations">
    <input ng-model="operation.detailText" type="text"></input>
    <div>
      <p>{{operation.detailText}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="operations.push({})">Add one more</button>
</div>
```

Note: operations here is an array, and it can be empty to start.

Comment: ok this way is working now, but if I click on that button, I am adding double inputs in another ng-model reproduced by a ng-repeat. [Look at this video, is with your implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIYNBIrc3wc&feature=youtu.be), and [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516454/adding-inputs-dynamically-not-working-properly#30516949)

Comment: You can't use the same array for both ng-repeats.
You could add a filter to the ng-repeat `ng-repeat="operation in operations | someOperationFilter`

Comment: Be clear in your code about the concepts you're using (i.e. `operations` vs `operationTypes`) and don't mix them into the same array like that.
http://jsbin.com/hujerurivu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: add that answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517983/avoid-angular-duplicates-on-ng-model/30518069?noredirect=1#comment49111269_30518069 actually works as I want. I can give you better answer

Answer (score 3):

A quick example:

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input/>
    </li>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1];
    $scope.add=function(){
      $scope.items.push($scope.items.length)
    }

}
```

Example ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/6592/)***

This is one way to do it. I simply add elements to the `items` which increases its length thereby adding one more input to it.

Comment: how I do it taking into account that the ng-model is operation.detailText

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer. Different inputs cannot have same ng model, however you can have an array for the ng-models.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer. Every input will have its own ng-model, as you press the add button you need to add a new ng-model to the newly created input.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer. The above code is just an example, you can modify it as per your requirement :)

Comment: Take a look at my answer. It accounts for ng-model.

Answer (score 1):

If your list of inputs will grow indefinitely the best option is, indeed, the `ng-repeat`, but if all you need is another, predefined, input, you can use an `ng-if` to add the markup.
Something like the following:

```
<div ng-if="inputAdded">
    <!-- input and other stuff in here -->
<div>

<button ng-click="inputAdded = true"></button>
```

Comment: how should I do it with ng-repeat then ?

Comment: Take a look at [Zee's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513316/how-to-dynamically-add-input-without-ng-repeat/30513473#30513514)