# Adding inputs dynamically not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue trying to add inputs dynamically.

I have this:

```
<button ng-click="operations.push({})">Add input</button>
```

which is adding inputs:

```
<div ng-repeat="operation in operations">
  <input ng-model="operation.detailText">
</div>
```

I have 2 columns, where I have exactly the same due to an ng-repeat, so, in both columns I have the adding inputs button, When I click on the button `Add input`, I am adding the inputs to both columns, which I don't want, I need to add those inputs only to the current input where I am working on.

I made a video for you to see what I am talking about.
[Here the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIYNBIrc3wc&feature=youtu.be)

Check here for the code: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qumuho/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: You need to put up more of your code.  This is likely doing this because the alias for both controllers (for each (column?)) is the same, but we can't know for sure without more.  Maybe consider making a fiddle?: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: all I have in the controller is this ```$scope.operations = [];``` @Grallen and yes, is the same controller. Look at the video.

Comment: each column needs it's own controller or the controller need an element in an array for each column (multidimensional array)

Comment: Can you show both the ng-repeat?

Comment: @Grallen is the same controller.

Comment: You have two forms, they are sharing one controller, so when they display they will both draw from the same pool of data(thus looking like duplicates).  They need their own unique pools of data.  Either by changing your code to give them each their own controller or to give them each their own unique spot in an array to store their own data.

Comment: @Zee here is the main parent: ```ng-repeat="operation in data.operations"```

Comment: @Grallen what ? it is just a simple ng-repeat where I am displaying those boxes/panels or whatever, so in some views there are 2 panels and in other views there are like 10 or 15, so everything is in the same controller. I thought that I need to put something like $index. But is way more complicated then I thought

Comment: Zee's answer is correct.

Comment: @Grallen you don't get it, I will be deleting this question in order to formulate a new one.

Comment: Make a working jsfiddle for the next time so you can avoid downvotes.

Comment: @Grallen and just to be clear: are not 2 forms.

Comment: I apologize, I was struggling with what the right word to describe the boxes.

Comment: @Grallen here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/qumuho/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the same array for both the `ng-repeat` that is

```
operations
```

So when  you click on `add button` it adds an empty object to `operations` and both the `ng-repeat` is affected since they both are using the same array.

You need to have different arrays, something like `operations` and `operations1` and then write the second `ng-repeat` with `operations1`

Comment: did you see the video ??? there are 2 boxes one above another, why those boxes needs to have different arrays or controllers if they are boxes reproduced due to a ng-repeat?. Then I have another ng-repeat because when I do click on ```add button```, I need it to reproduce infinite amount of inputs. I thought that by doing something like $index in any part will fix my issue.