# Avoid angular duplicates on ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am adding inputs dynamically by pressing an `add button`

[here is a JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/qumuho/1/edit?html,js,output) so you can check my issue.

Everytime I press the button I mentioned, a new input should comes up, as you can see I have in the same view 2 forms/boxes there generated by a `ng-repeat` with separate inputs and a separate `add more` button, the issue is that when I play that button, 2 new inputs comes up in the 2 different forms I have, that shouldn't be happening, the new input must be add it only in the current form.

```
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="op in operation track by $index">
            <p>{{op.title}} | {{op.duration}} | {{op.status}}</p>
            <input ng-model="operation.detailText" type="text"></input>
            <div>
                <div ng-repeat="operation in operations track by $index">

                    <input ng-model="operation.detailText" type="text"></input>

                </div>
                <button ng-click="operations.push({})">Add one more</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('ionicApp',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.operations = [];

    $scope.operation = [];

    $scope.operation = [{
                    title    : 'Operación 170794',
                    duration : '3600',
                    status   : '0'
                  }, {
                    title    : 'Operación 981922',
                    duration : '60',
                    status   : '0'
                  }];

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have 2 things point to the same array and have a different output. JavaScript objects are by reference and an array is an object. So both of your lists were reading from the same array. If you add a key operations to each of the objects and push to that it will keep the lists separate.

You want to add a key operations to your operation objects like so:

```
angular.module('ionicApp',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.operation = [{
      title    : 'Operación 170794',
      duration : '3600',
      status   : '0',
      operations: []
    }, {
      title    : 'Operación 981922',
      duration : '60',
      status   : '0',
      operations: []
    }];

});
```

Then change your loops like so:

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="op in operation track by $index">
                <p>{{op.title}} | {{op.duration}} | {{op.status}}</p>
                <input ng-model="operation.detailText" type="text"></input>
                <div>
                    <div ng-repeat="operation in op.operations track by $index">

                        <input ng-model="operation.detailText" type="text"></input>

                    </div>
                    <button ng-click="op.operations.push({})">Add one more</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

You can also add an index to each operation you push to operations and filter by it with ng-if:

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="op in operation track by $index">
    <p>{{op.title}} | {{op.duration}} | {{op.status}}</p>
    <input ng-model="operation.detailText" type="text"></input>
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="operation in operations track by $index" ng-if="operation._index === $index">

            <input ng-model="operation.detailText" type="text"></input>

        </div>
        <button ng-click="addOperation($index)">Add one more</button>
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('ionicApp',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.operations = [];

    $scope.operation = [{
      title    : 'Operación 170794',
      duration : '3600',
      status   : '0'
    }, {
      title    : 'Operación 981922',
      duration : '60',
      status   : '0'
    }];

    $scope.addOperation = function(index){
        $scope.operations.push({
            _index: index
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Is it out of the question to manage them this way on the front end then concat the operation.operations array into 1 array before sending it to the server?

Comment: Ok, I will work on it this way for now, once I get the real data from the DB, probably I will need your help, thank you :)

Comment: Updated answer with a 2nd thing you can try

Answer (score 3):

Be clear in your code about the concepts you're using (i.e. operations vs operationTypes) and don't mix them together. Avoid naming things too similarly as it creates unnecessary confusion.

jsbin.com/hujerurivu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
angular.module('ionicApp',[]).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.operationTypes = [{
                    title    : 'Operación 170794',
                    duration : '3600',
                    status   : '0'
                  }, {
                    title    : 'Operación 981922',
                    duration : '60',
                    status   : '0'
                  }];

    $scope.operations = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.operationTypes, function(operationType){
        $scope.operations[operationType.title] = [];
    });
});
```

--

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="operationType in operationTypes track by $index">
            <p>{{operationType.title}} | {{operationType.duration}} | {{operationType.status}}</p>
            <div>
                <div ng-repeat="operation in operations[operationType.title] track by $index">
                    <input ng-model="operation.detailText" type="text"></input>
                </div>
                <button ng-click="operations[operationType.title].push({})">Add one more</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add an array to each of the 'operation' objects you can loop through those separately as seen below:

This will keep the forms and inputs separate.

http://jsbin.com/tapeje/5/edit